# PHP / MYSQL - how to scale same tasks for hundreds of instances

Tags: php, mysql, cron

PHP.

I plan to have many users (instances) of which I need to run a daily task for.

Each instance takes around 5 mins for the script to complete the task,

task: querying an API getting data, inputting into database, editing data, updating API with the results.

What's the correct way to handle this.

Currently I have been writing code looping through each instance and doing the repeating task for each user until gone through all users, but if each instance took 5 mins and I had to run it daily I could only have a max of 288 users (24 hours)

So I guess one work around is to some how query the database then do a cron job for each instance?

Or is there a way you can php to loop all instances and get them to do it all at the same time? or would this take too much resources.

Please help.

Comment: 5 minutes seems like an incredibly long time to do a per-user task. You probably should address whatever is making that so slow rather than worrying about optimising how you run the task.

Comment: Hi, thanks I exaggerated to get my point across, either way I am wanting to know the correct way to do this?

Comment: You can implement queue system with workers. You can have multiple worker processes that pick up tasks from the queue and execute them.

Comment: Maybe think about a scalable microservices architecture, especially if you're doing SaaS

Comment: Maybe you should look into ways to safely parallelise your application. Whether that's feasible or not depends on the details of your application. There's also the danger of it slowing it down if you're thrashing a mechanical hard drive for data all over the place for example, so parallelising is generally not a simple problem.

Comment: Also, one giant loop running for 24 hours is probably going to leak memory over time. You might even find an optimization by having your single loop only take 10 (or so) at a time. But also go for multiple workers at the start, that's probably the easiest optimization without touching too much of the code.